# How can I see absolute coordinates?

Tags: vertices

Is there a way to see the absolute coordinates of a vertex?
I'm using a math formula in Excel to define points.

Answer (score 3):

You can see both global and local coordinates for selected elements from the *3D View > Tool Shelf > Transform* Panel.

There you will find a button to toggle Between global and local.

[image]

Have in mind that this may not take into account mesh deformations caused by modifiers or armatures.

To take those into account you may end up having to convert to mesh or applying all modifiers.

Comment: Where can I find this in newer Blender versions? (>3.0). It seems to have disappeared.

Answer (score 1):

I just found this answer on another site:
"If you want global coordinates, I see only a workaround myself : snap the 3D cursor to your vertex by selecting it and then using Shift+S and then Cursor -> Selection and then read the position of the 3D cursor in the View, View Properties panel."

Answer (score 0):

The *View* menu (available in Layout, Modeling, Sculpting, and others), enable Sidebar. Or, press the <kbd>N</kbd> key as a shortcut.

[image: View menu]

The Sidebar pops up on the upper right of the view. Select a vertex in *Edit Mode*, you'll see the coordinates, which you can view as *Global* or *Local*.

[image: Sidebar]

The Sidebar also gives dimensions for selected objects.